# Searching a file with the contents of another file python

Tags: python, file, list, search, strip

I have a file that has a unique ID number on each line. I am trying to search a different file for the occurrences of these ID numbers and return the line where these id numbers are in the second file, in this case into an output file. I am new to programming and this is what I have so far.

```
outlist = []
with open('readID.txt', 'r') as readID, \
     open('GOlines.txt', 'w') as output, \
     open('GO.txt', 'r') as GO:  
     x = readID.readlines()
     print x
     for line in GO:
        if x[1:-1] in line:
        outlist.append(line)
        outlist.append('\n')

     if x[1:-1] in line:
        outlist.append(line)
        outlist.append('\n')
     print outlist
     output.writelines(outlist)
```

The files look like this: readID.txt

```
00073810.1
00082422.1
00018647.1
00063072.1
```

GO.txt

```
#query  GO  reference DB    reference family    
HumanDistalGut_READ_00048904.2  GO:0006412  TIGRFAM TIGR00001    
HumanDistalGut_READ_00043244.3  GO:0022625  TIGRFAM TIGR00001    
HumanDistalGut_READ_00048644.4  GO:0000315  TIGRFAM TIGR00001   
HumanDistalGut_READ_00067264.5  GO:0003735  TIGRFAM TIGR00001
```

The read ids match up with some but not all of the ids after *READ*...

Comment: To fix the Attribute error instead of using readlines() do x=readID.read().splitlines()

Comment: `x` is a `list` of lines, not just a single one. So, you have to do `x = [line.strip('\n') for line in x]` to `strip` all of them. But, as @SuperFamousGuy suggests, it's easier to just read them without the newlines in the first place.

Comment: Thanks that does help. I also noticed that it should be for x[] in line not GO and it works for a discrete value of the x list but it doesn't like the x[1:-1]. TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: Are you trying to match 00073810.1 or 00073810? Where is it supposed to match in GO.txt? `READ_[ID].2`, `READ_[ID]`, or `GO:[ID]`? Can you see now how it's difficult to answer your question with so many missing details? :p

Comment: I Apologize again. The full number including the decimal should match the READ_[ID]. I am mining for the GO:# which I can isolate after I have the entire line in the output file. Thanks again for helping me out I am quite lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import re

def extract_id(line):
    """
    input: HumanDistalGut_READ_00048904.2  GO:0006412  TIGRFAM TIGR00001
    returns: 00048904.2
    """
    result = re.search(r'READ_(\d{8}\.\d)', line)
    if result != None:
        return result.group(1)
    else:
        return None

def extract_go_num(line):
    """
    input: HumanDistalGut_READ_00048904.2  GO:0006412  TIGRFAM TIGR00001
    returns: 0006412
    """
    result = re.search(r'GO:(\d{7})', line)
    if result != None:
        return result.group(1)
    else:
        return None

def main(argv = None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    with open('readID.txt', 'r') as f:
        ids = frozenset(f.readlines())

    with open('GO.txt', 'r') as haystack, \
        open('GOLines.txt', 'w') as output:

        for line in haystack:
            if extract_id(line) in ids:
                output.write(extract_go_num(line) + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm trading memory overhead for an O(n) solution rather than O(n^2).

I'm using regular expressions to extract the ids and go numbers, but it's brittle if the number of digits change.

Comment: I forgot to strip newlines when comparing ids.

Comment: It works with my test input. At a certain point all we can do is provide possible solutions / general ideas; we can't do everything for you. Try to understand why something works or doesn't work. If you don't understand something, then break it down into smaller pieces and test it out yourself or ask questions. Generic responses like "it's still empty" is not helpful to you or me.

Comment: I apologize you are right. I am not sure why it isn't working for me ill try to mess around with it more.

Comment: Thank you very much William! This did seem to work and no worries on the brittleness the format is very strict. Ill do some more back checking to make sure but it looks good. Would you mind explaining this it looks like a complicated script? Again thanks for your time.

Comment: Which parts do you have questions about?

Comment: So you are matching the ID's to eachother which you have defined as {n} digits after a certain text. And then returning the GO[ID]. I guess I don't get the argv part. One last thing.. say I wanted to return the entire line not just the GO[ID] is it possible with this format to manipulate the extract_go_num part to do this?

Comment: Regarding matching ids, yes. Regular expressions are powerful but a bit complicated: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ argv part is just standard boilerplate for handling command line arguments. If you want the entire line, modify output.write() to write the line instead of the number.

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thank you William you have been a tremendous help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
with open('readID.txt', 'r') as readID, open('GOlines.txt', 'w') as output, open('GO.txt', 'r') as GO:
    for ID in readID:
        for line in GO:
            if ID in line:
                output.write(line)
```

Comment: Hmmm, could you post some input IDs and some data from GO.txt?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are small enough to fit in your memory.

```
with open('/somepath/GO.txt') as f:
    pool = f.readlines()

with open('/somepath/readID.txt') as f:    
    tokens = f.readlines()

# strip spaces/new lines
tokens = [t.strip() for t in tokens]
found = [(t, lno) for t in tokens for (lno, l) in enumerate(pool) if t in l]
```

You could then print your `found` list into your outfile.

Comment: I like this one but the i think the file is too big the GO file is 80Mb.. when i run this script it seems to just freeze up the terminal.